# Vaadin 7 + Spring Boot Security handle Access Dined exceptions

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a Spring service method annotated with `@PreAuthorize`:

```
@Override
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('PERMISSION_CREATE_DECISION')")
public Decision createProduct(String name, String description, String url)
```

When I try to access this method from code with not authorized user I'm receiving AccessDeniedException:

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83)
```

that is absolutely fine.

in this case I need to forward this user to the application login page.

How to do it in Vaadin 7 + Spring Security ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UI class set custom ErrorHandler that deals with catching AccessDeniedException (thrown anywhere in application), invalidating session and redirection.

```
@SpringUI
public class CustomUI extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(final VaadinRequest request) {
        setErrorHandler(new CustomErrorHandler());
    }
}

public class CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    @SuppressWarnings("ThrowableResultOfMethodCallIgnored")
    @Override
    public void error(ErrorEvent event) {
        Throwable finalCause = getFinalCause(event.getThrowable());
        if (AccessDeniedException.class.isAssignableFrom(finalCause.getClass())) {
            // do everything you need
            UI.getCurrent().getSession().close();                   //close Vaadin session
            UI.getCurrent().getSession().getSession().invalidate(); //close Http session
            UI.getCurrent().getPage().setLocation("/login");        //redirect..
            UI.getCurrent().getNavigator().navigateTo("viewName");      //... or using navigator
            return;
        }

        DefaultErrorHandler.doDefault(event);
    }

    private Throwable getFinalCause(Throwable throwable) {
        while (throwable.getCause() != null) {
            throwable = throwable.getCause();
        }
        return throwable;
    }
}
```